# How To Get The Original Key From Sliced Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code :

```
<?php

$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 33, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 9, 8, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 3, 24, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 2, 10, NULL),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 17, 11, 28000));

$num = 2;

foreach(array_slice($order_list, $num) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'=>'.$value[2].'<br>';
}

?>
```

and the result is this :

```
0=>3
1=>2
2=>17
```

the problem is... `$value = 3` has `$key = 0`, while in the `$order_list` this value has `$key = 2`.

so, I'm expecting `$key` from `$order_list` based on value sliced. how to do that?

thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the fourth arg for `array_slice()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

....and the manual says: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

The fourth argument, preserve_keys.